# Nested loops; multiplying two numbers

Tags: python, loops, iteration, multiplication

I want to get a list with the product of 0.0 with 0.0 through 0.9. And then 0.1 through 0.9. And so on. So the total number of elements in my list has to be 100. This code is not working. Any help?

```
p=0.0
dp=0.1
p_ray= []
while p < 0.9:
  t = 0.0
  dt = 0.1
  t_ray = []
  u_ray = []
  while t <= 0.9:
      u=t*p
      u_ray.append(u)
      t=t+dt
  p=p+dp
print(u_ray)
```

Comment: You declare `u_ray` again at each iteration, losing all previous values. Try to put `u_ray` declaration before `while`. Also why do you need variables `p_ray` and `t_ray`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am new to python. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A new list get created at each iteration of the outer loop, declare it only one time at the beginning, even assigning every time to `dt` is superfluous if you don't want its value to change

```
p = 0.0
dp = 0.1
dt = 0.1
p_ray = []
t_ray = []
u_ray = []


while p < 0.9:
    t = 0.0

    while t <= 0.9:
        u = t * p
        u_ray.append(u)
        t += dt
    
    p += dp

print(u_ray)
```